# SVN opposite of cp?

Tags: svn

`svn cp` will cause a branch in svn's history, where one file becomes two.  What I want to do is the opposite of this, where two files become one in the repo history.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch is not "one file becomes two" but adding a new link in the repository to the copy-source with the same history, so I asume that's what you want. There is no way to merge the history of two files. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html

Comment: So I guess what you're saying is that the SVN history is a tree, not a graph.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

svn merge is the opposite of branching (using the cp command).

So you branch, and now you have 2 copies of the file, you make changes to one of them and want to bring those changes back to the original... that's [merging.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html)

This is all you need to do to bring the "2 to 1" aspect. the log history is retained, however the usual log command only shows the revisions, ignoring the branched history, so you'd only see a single revision for the merge. You can see the full history, including the individual commits on the branch by using [the -g option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.logblame)